# Delete content of Azure pipeline blob storage via Azure release

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I’m trying to build a CICD pipeline. I want to copy my new static React build bundle to Azure blob storage. As part of this, the old content needs to be deleted. The only action I seem able to take, however, is copy. Is it possible to do this?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is not possible to delete/clean up the blob content using `Azure File Copy`.

You can use `Azure CLI` task to invoke the `az` cmdlets to clean up your container before running the `Azure File Copy` task.

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <storage_account_name> --source <container_name>
```

[image]